# Substitute existing Customer EAV Attributes

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, eav, customer-attribute

In a Magento CE 1.7.0.2 shop I have custom EAV attributes for customer and customer addresses (`eav_entity_type` 1 and 2), such as:

- `name_one`
- `name_two`
- `name_three`
- `telephonetel`

instead of the standard ones:

- `firstname`
- `lastname`
- `company`
- `telephone`

A lot of customers and orders exist with this custom structure. Now I want to change the attributes back to the Magento standard fields to avoid problems with third party modules.

When I change the customer address field template in the backend, I suppose that afterwards in the existing datasets the related attribute data is missing in frontend and backend.

What is the best way to change back the attributes but still preserve information of the existing customer and order data?

I think of this way:

- Change customer address template in backend
- Adjust frontend template for registration, customer account address fields, checkout, etc.
- Copy data from old custom attributes to the original standard magento attributes: Can somebody give me an example how to implement this?

Comment: Put an observer on customer save, to insert values from standard customer attributes to your new created, to maintain backward compatibility.